# Error code 120013 when trying to create transport

Tags: pjsip

pj_status_t returns me a 120013 error when I'm trying to set UDP transport with the pjsua_transport_create function

What does that mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

googled it, the only [result](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/issues/detail?id=781) says something like

> Permission Denied (120013)

Looks like you don't have permission to do something,
maybe you are using a non-standard port?

Comment: You were right!! I missed to allow network connections in my Manifest file, what a noob!
Thanks

Comment: Hello, sorry to bump this, where is this Manifest and where are these permissions set?

Comment: Hello, sorry this was long time ago, I can't remember exactly. But there's a manifest file (called 'Manifest' or something similar) in which you can define what permissions the application has. In this case the problem was that the application did not have the permission to access the network.

Answer (score 0):

Android: Add these permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml as a direct child of the manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sipapp" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```